# При выборе checkbox брать их value и добавлять кнопке в onclick через пробел

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно при выборе checkbox брать их value и добавлять кнопке в onclick через пробел, а при снятии определенного checkbox его значение убиралось

```
<div class="products-cont">
    <div class="products">
        <input id="product-1" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="add('1');">
        <input id="product-2" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="add('2');">
        <input id="product-3" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="add('3');">
        <input id="product-4" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="add('4');">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-cont">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-main prod-btn-1" onclick="add('8');">Добавить</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Буду очень признателен за любую помощь.

Comment: "добавлять кнопке в onclick через пробел" - ??

Comment: @Igor
да, через пробел, вот так onclick="add('1'); add('3'); add('8');"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что "пробел" здесь ни при чем.

```js
function add(a) {
  console.log(a);
}

$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  var $btn = $('.prod-btn-1');
  if (this.checked) {
    $btn.attr("onclick", $btn.attr("onclick") + this.value);
  } else {
    $btn.attr("onclick", $btn.attr("onclick").replace(this.value, ""));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products-cont">
  <div class="products">
    <input id="product-1" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="add('1');">
    <input id="product-2" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="add('2');">
    <input id="product-3" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="add('3');">
    <input id="product-4" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="add('4');">
  </div>
  <div class="btn-cont">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-main prod-btn-1" onclick="add('8');">Добавить</button>
  </div>
</div>
```